# I am unable to retrieve data from database in android from sqlite without php or any

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am doing a project, where I need to retrieve data from sqlite database, but unable to do that. Kindly help me through out.

my login code

```
package com.example.pallavi.myproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Login extends Activity{
    Intent i=null;

    EditText tv1,tv4;
    boolean flag=false;
    SQLiteDatabase db=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        tv1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone2);
        tv4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password2);
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("mydb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);



         }
    public void action(View v)
    {

                String mobile_no=tv1.getText().toString();
                String password=tv4.getText().toString();

              /*  if(mobile_no==null||mobile_no=="")
                {
                    show("Please Enter Correct mobile number.");
                }
                else if(password==null||password=="")
                {
                    show("Please Enter Correct Password.");
                }
                else*/
                {


                    show("Query is not executing");
                    String[] args={"null"};
                    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from login where mobile_no='"+mobile_no+"'",args);
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    show("not going inside");

                    if(c.getCount()>0)
                    {
                        show("Success fully login");
                        i=new Intent(this,post.class);

                        db.close();
                        finish();
                    }
                    else
                        show("Wrong Password or Mobile number.");

                }

        }
    public void acc(View v)
    {
        if (v.getId()==R.id.button)
        {

            Intent i=new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    }

    public void show(String str)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

kindly check through it.
I am trying to retrieve data from db and check, but it is not performing the operation.

Comment: what do you mean under "not performing the operation"? No data in database? Some method is not being called? You get an exception?

Comment: i have database and even values too, I am not getting values and condition checked.And no exeception raised too

Comment: When you call openOrCreateDatabase(), you should be calling it in a static way : SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(). It is weird that your code even compile.

Comment: I don't see you calling method action() anywhere. Are you setting onclick listeners in XML? Never do it. It is forbidden.

Comment: How i cannot set my buttton to onclick, it wouldn't work if i dont do it any alternatives

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve data from SQLite for log in use this Code:

```
 public void login_user(View view) {

        editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        editTextID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editTextID.setFocusable(true);

        username = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
        password = editTextID.getText().toString();

        final String idd = password;
        final String name = username;

        if (password.equals("")) {
            editTextID.setError("Enter User Id");
            editTextID.requestFocus();
        } else if (username.equals("")) {
            editTextUserName.setError("Enter User Name");
            editTextUserName.requestFocus();
        } else {
            String storedPassword = databaseHelper.getSinUserlgeEntry(username,password);
            // check if the Stored password matches with  Password entered by user
            if (password.equals(storedPassword)) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Congrats: Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                View vieew = toast.getView();
                //  vieew.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BD8BDC"));
                vieew.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textinputborder);
                toast.setView(vieew);
                //  TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                /*here you can do anything with text*/
                toast.show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, user_home.class);
                intent.putExtra("Name", username);
                intent.putExtra("ID", password);
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                View vieew = toast.getView();
                //  vieew.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BD8BDC"));
                vieew.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textinputborder);
                toast.setView(vieew);
                //  TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                /*here you can do anything with text*/
                toast.show();
            }
            editTextUserName.setText("");
            editTextID.setText("");
            editTextID.requestFocus();
        }
    }
```

Finally use this in SQLite Database class :

```
  public String getSinUserlgeEntry(String userName, String Id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Cursor cursor = db.query("day_info", null, " emp_name=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_name, null, emp_name + " LIKE '%" + userName + "%' AND " + main_IDD + " LIKE '%" + Id + "%'", null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() < 1) // UserName Not Exist
        {
            cursor.close();
            return "NOT EXIST";
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String iddd = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mid"));
        cursor.close();
        return iddd;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to retrieve data from Sqlite.

First use this code where you need retrieved data :

```
 OurAppsPackages = new ArrayList<String>();
        OurAppsPackages = databaseHelper.getOurAllAppsPackage();
```

Use bellow code in B2MDatabaseHelper class where your database.

```
 public ArrayList<String> getOurAllAppsPackage() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Cursor cursor = db.query("day_info", null, " emp_name=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        ArrayList<String> pkgs= new ArrayList<String>();

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
                String pkgN = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PackageName"));
                pkgs.add(pkgN.toString());
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        return pkgs;
    }
```

Comment: can i know about databasehelper

Comment: B2MDatabaseHelper  is a class where you can create SQLite database